# Button with pointed edges and shadow

Tags: css, button, geometry, css-shapes

I'm trying to make a **CSS button** . As you can see below, I'm not able to create a gradient for the second HTML-element for the corners. Normally I would use borders or simply rotate a element to create a triangle with a gradient, but the problem is that my triangle isn't a 90 degree square.

Desired design: (Grayscale, retina 200% zoomed)

[image: Desired CSS button]

My CSS button: (Blue, retina 200% zoomed)

[image: Actual CSS button]

Is there a better way to create this button with CSS?

http://jsfiddle.net/G8ZBz/ or simply read below:

HTML-code

```
<div class="button">
    <div class="button-inside"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
    width: 225px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #2983d2;
}
.button:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    left: -13px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 13px solid #2983d2;
}
.button:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    top: 0;
    right: -13px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 13px solid #2983d2;
}
.button .button-inside {
    position: relative;
    width: 221px;
    height: 55px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    background: #469bf9; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #469bf9 50%, #1e80f7 50%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,#469bf9), color-stop(50%,#1e80f7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #469bf9 50%, #1e80f7 50%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #469bf9 50%, #1e80f7 50%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #469bf9 50%, #1e80f7 50%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #469bf9 50%, #1e80f7 50%); /* W3C */
}
.button .button-inside:before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    left: -13px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-right: 13px solid #1e80f7; /* should be a gradient */
}
.button .button-inside:after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    top: 0;
    right: -13px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left: 13px solid #1e80f7; /* should be a gradient */
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to make the same shape as the first grey button in blue with CSS?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The design is in grayscale, but I'm trying to make a blue button that looks exactly like it. I'll update my post to clarify this.

Comment: Min. browser requirements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [skew property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#skew) to make flat triangles.

In your case, I would use the `skew()` properties and background-shadows to make the bottom border effect :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/g9tvc/)**

Output :

[image: CSS button]

The following image explains what is what and how each element, pseudo elements and background-shadows are used to form the button. Pseudo elements and background-shadows are used to minimize markup:

[image: How to make a CSS button]

*HTML :*

```
<div class="button top">
    <div class="button bottom"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
.top{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:150px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 60px;
}
.button:before, .button:after{
    position: absolute;
    width:70%; height:50%;    
    content: "";  
    z-index:-1;
}
.top:before {
    left:0; top:0;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-20deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(-20deg);
    transform:skewX(-20deg);
    background: #469BF9;
    box-shadow: -5px 10px 0px -5px #104f96;
    z-index:-2;
}
.top:after {
    right:0; top:0;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(20deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(20deg);
    transform:skewX(20deg);
    background: #469BF9;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 0px -5px #104f96;
    z-index:-2;
}
.bottom:before{
    left:0; top:50%;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(20deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(20deg);
    transform:skewX(20deg);
    background: #1E80F7;
    box-shadow: -4px 5px 0px 0px #104f96;
}
.bottom:after{
    right:0; top:50%;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-20deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(-20deg);
    transform:skewX(-20deg);
    background: #1E80F7;
    box-shadow: 4px 5px 0px 0px #104f96;
}
```

You may also check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/IjKvp) with a few different triangles.

Comment: +1 very nice work! Could use some more explanation though. Otherwise it's just c&p without understanding.

Comment: Thx guys! @Christoph added an image that explain how each element is placed, I hope it is understandable.

Comment: Wow, this is absolutely  great! Thank you, you're a genius!

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this shape using a single element by doing the following:

- a single parent element with a `perspective` assigned to it.
- two pseudo-elements which are both half the height of the single parent element and are rotated in opposite directions. The perspective on the parent means they get displayed like trapezoids.
- positioning the two pseudo-elements exactly one below the other to make them look like they are two pieces of the same shape.
- box shadow on the pseudo-element to produce the shadow effect on the bottom side.

```css
.hex-with-shadow {
  position: relative;
  width: 225px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 10px;
  -moz-perspective: 10px;
  perspective: 10px;
}
.hex-with-shadow:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -1px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #469BF9;
  box-shadow: 0px 3.5px 0px 0px #104f96;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(3deg);
  transform: rotateX(3deg);
}
.hex-with-shadow:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #1E80F7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #104f96;
  box-shadow: -4px 3px 0px #104f96, 4px 3px 0px #104f96;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-3deg);
  transform: rotateX(-3deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="hex-with-shadow"></div>
```

**Final Output:**

[image]

---

**Original Answer:**

You can use the below method to create the triangle and also give a gradient to it.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/G8ZBz/9/)

**Note to Future readers:** The second approach is very hacky and not re-usable. Also, this one causes slight distortions in Firefox.

Comment: looks quite off in FF. Vendor prefixes?

Comment: @Phlume: Updated the demo with vendor prefixes now mate. Should look much better with it :)